# passing multiple(different) types of arguments to a template function

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    int one;
    int i;
    int s;  
};

template<class myType>
void serialize(myType b, string &a, int epe) {

    //three.resize(42);
    int type = typeid(b).name()[35] == 'S' ? 1 : 0; // testing if the map(b) value weather a struct                                or an int

    if (type) {
        auto it = b.begin();
        cout << sizeof(it->second) / sizeof(int) << endl;
        cout << it->second.one;
    } else {
        cout << sizeof(b) / sizeof(int) << endl;
    }

}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    map<int, int> hey;

    map<int, foo> heya {
        { 1, { 66 } },
    };

    typedef map<int, foo> mappy;
    typedef map<int, int> happy;

    string duck;
    auto it = heya.begin();
    serialize<happy>(hey, duck, 4);
    serialize<mappy>(heya, duck, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

So I am getting this error, i think its because its testing the map
 with value of the type int`(map<int,int>)` on a part of the template
 function which shouldn't reach its an int not a struct, even though I
 tried specialization the type before using the function, still not working.

```
serialize\main.cpp|36|error: request for member 'one' in      'it.std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::operator->
   [with _Tp = std::pair<const int, int>, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::pointer = std::pair<const int, int>*]()->std::pair<const int, int>::second', 
  which is of non-class type 'int'|
  ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Comment: `second` is of type `int` so it doesn't have a member called `one`. You need to provide an overload if you want to provide support for a specific type.

Comment: `typeid` is a poor way to do it anyway, since `name()`'s result is implementation-defined. For metaprogramming, use `std::is_same`.

Answer (score 0):

`if` is evaluated only at runtime.

At compile time, the compiler doesn't know whether the `if` is going to be true or false when compiling. So in general, all the code has to be compilable irrespective of whether it's inside a condition or not.

You need to use an overloaded function.

```
typedef map<int, foo> mappy;
typedef map<int, int> happy;

template<class myType>
void serialize(myType b, string &a, int epe) {
    cout << sizeof(b) / sizeof(int) << endl;
}

void serialize(mappy b, string &a, int epe) {
    auto it = b.begin();
    cout << sizeof(it->second) / sizeof(int) << endl;
    cout << it->second.one;
}

serialize<happy>(hey, duck, 4);
serialize(heya, duck, 4);
```

Comment: Argh! beat me to it. That's what I get for making a milkshake.

Comment: hmm, thanks but isn't there any chance to do it in another way without using an overloaded function?